# Object return without assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working through the [Eloquent JavaScript tutorial](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) -  **Recognizing text**.

I have a hard time understanding where the object assignment takes place for the else clause of the condition inside my `for` / `of` loop. The only assignment I see is if `findIndex` returns -1, yet when I run the code it also creates an object for all values returning `true`. How is this possible that it has a name value and where does this get assigned?

```js
function countBy(array, groupName) {
    let counts = [];

    for (let item of array) {
        let name = groupName(item);
        let known = counts.findIndex(count => count.name == name);

        if (known == -1) {
            counts.push({ name, count: 1 });
        } else {               
            counts[known].count++;
        }
    }
    return counts;
}

console.log(countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 2));
// → [{name: false, count: 2}, {name: true, count: 3}]
```

Comment: My bad. The array has been expanded to include truthy values

Comment: name is from counts.push({ name, count: 1 }); which is same as counts.push({ name: name, count: 1 });

Comment: I understand the destructing part

Answer (score 2):

The `countBy` function partitions an array into segments labeled with names returned from the specified callback function.

In your case the callback function is `n => n > 2`, which can return `true` or `false`, so your input array will be partitioned into segments named `true` and `false`.

In the code, `counts` is the array of segments seen so far.

```
let known = counts.findIndex(count => count.name == name);
```

checks whether we have seen a segment whose name is `name` before. If we have, its index is in `known` and we can increment its count directly. If not (`known == -1`), we add it as a new segment with an initial count of `1` and a name of `name`.

Comment: So `let known = counts.findIndex(...)` adds the key `name` to all objects inside `counts`?

Comment: @FlorestanKorp No, `findIndex` doesn't modify `counts`. All objects already have a `name` property from when they were added in `counts.push({ name, count: 1 });`.

Comment: Got it. findIndex() gets called on an empty array the first time ALWAYS returning -1 and therefore ALWAYS instantiating an object in the if() clause.

Answer (score 0):

`findIndex(`) gets called on an empty array the first time ALWAYS returning -1 and therefore ALWAYS instantiating an object in the `if(known == -1)` clause.